# How to make a onmouseover work in mysql catalog

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, hover, onmouseover

I'm having difficulty creating a button on my catalog page, the catalog page returns either 8 15 or 20 products from a mysql database so i use a loop to pull each product out of the database, and i need a addtocart button which uses javascript to create an onmouseover effect the code is as follows

```
echo "<a href=\"catalog.php?buyproduct=$productNumber\" onmouseover=\"document.crt.src='images/addcrt_btn_dn.png'\"
onmouseout=\"document.crt.src='images/addcrt_btn.png'\">
<img src=\"images/addcrt_btn.png\" name=\"crt\" alt=\"Add to cart\" width=\"81\" height=\"24\"> </a>";
```

it displays the image properly but nothing happens when the mouse is put over the image. I'm guessing that this could be caused because since either 8 15 or 20 of these images are being created, the "name=crt" is throwing the whole thing off, if so how could i fix this?

Any advice would be helpful thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the name attribute on the `<img>`, I would start by recommending you use the `id` attribute, as follows:

```
<img id="crt" />
```

Then you can change the `src` as follows:

```
document.getElementById('crt').src = 'images/addcrt_btn_dn.png';
```

Make sure you properly escape all those quotes properly, or work on generating the content another way (here's an example sticking with the `name` attribute):

```
...
?>
<a href="catalog.php?buyproduct=<?php=$productNumber?>" onmouseover="document[crt].src='images/addcrt_btn_dn.png'" onmouseout="document[crt].src='images/addcrt_btn.png'">
<img src="images/addcrt_btn.png" name="crt" alt="Add to cart" width="81" height="24">
</a>
<?php
...
```

Comment: thank you for your help Dolph, why is the id preferred over name?

Comment: `name` attributes are not required to be unique, while `id` attributes are required to be unique identifiers on the page. When accessing elements through the DOM using JavaScript, it's obviously more convenient to be able to access a specific object by it's unique `id`. Normally when you want to access an element by `name`, you'll get an array of elements back, even if there is only one element with that given `name`.

Comment: o i see! well for some reason I still can't get this to work here's my new code

<a href="catalog.php?page=1&fpage=25&spage=29&buyproduct=32403"  onmouseover="document[crt].src='images/addcrt_btn_dn.png'" onmouseout="document[crt].src='images/addcrt_btn.png'"> 
 
 <img src="images/addcrt_btn.png" id="crt" alt="Add to cart" width="81" height="24">

Comment: The code you just posted is mixing `id` and `name`. `document[crt]` accesses `crt` by name, but you also changed the `name` attribute to `id`. Instead of `document[crt]`, access the `id="crt"` using `document.getElementById('crt')`.

Comment: well thanks for your patience sir, im not so hot with js as im sure you've noticed, here's what i got now <a href="catalog.php?page=1&fpage=25&spage=29&buyproduct=37900"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('crt').src='images/addcrt_btn_dn.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('crt').src='images/addcrt_btn.png'"> 
whats happening with this is when i hover the mouse over the second addtocart button only the first src is switched, same with the third, do you think i need to somehow use an array to differentiate between each button?

Comment: just in case anybody is curious, i just used a counter inside the loop (which pulls each product out of the database) and used it on the end of the crt like this: crt$itemCount in the ID and in the link that way it was unique each time it read. :)